# Inequality + Sets Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let x,y,z be sets in universe U

if  $x\subseteq$ y, then  $x-z\subseteq y-z$

How to prove this formally?

Comment: You mean : if $x \subseteq y$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p \in x-z$, that is $p \in x$ and $p \notin z$.

It suffices to prove that $p \in y$, are you able to complete the proof?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $ x \subseteq y$

Answer (score 0):

The complete proof would go something like this:

Assume $x\subseteq y$
Then $a\in x \rightarrow a\in y$
Then $x-z \subseteq y$ (Since $x-z \subseteq x \land x\subseteq y$)
Then $x-z \cap z = \emptyset$. Therefore, $x-z \subseteq y-z$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in x-z \implies $

$a \in x \& a \not \in z \implies $

$a\in y \& a \not \in z \implies $

$a \in y-z $

So $x -z \subset y-z $

Comment: That skips a lot, for example, the relationship between y and z are introduced out of nowhere.

Comment: They were given in the statement of the question.

Comment: X subset y was given in the statement of the problem. z can be any set.